# Add a fadein fade out in jQuery, on multiple conditional statements

Tags: jquery, html

**Task:** On click of `li` navigation filter show and hide content with a transitional fadein fade out.

**Problem**  I'm just guessing and checking on where to place this fadein//fadeout transition.  Furthermore, I feel like my code is too inefficiency because I'm using 4 conditional statements. Would stack lead me in creating a solution to improve the overall logic of this script so I can just make a pretty transition :c?

**[LIVE CODE](http://designobvio.us/ie/)**

**jQuery Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//attach a single click listener on li elements
$('li.navCenter').on('click', function () {

    // get the id of the clicked li
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    // match current id with string check then apply filter
    if (id == 'printInteract') {
        //reset all the boxes for muliple clicks 
        $(".box").find('.video, .print, .web').closest('.box').show();

        $(".box").find('.web, .video').closest('.box').hide();

        $(".box").find('.print').show();
    }

    if (id == 'webInteract') {
        $(".box").find('.video, .print, .web').closest('.box').show();
        $(".box").find('.print, .video').closest('.box').hide();
        $(".box").find('.web').show();
    }
    if (id == 'videoInteract') {
        $(".box").find('.video, .print, .web').closest('.box').show();
        $(".box").find('.print, .web').closest('.box').hide()
        $(".box").find('.video').show();
    }
    if (id == 'allInteract') {
        $(".box").find('.video, .print, .web').closest('.box').show();
    }



});
```

**HTML Selected**

```
<nav>
<ul class="navSpaces">
    <li id="allInteract" class="navCenter">
        <a id="activeAll" class="navBg" href="#"><div class="relativeCenter"><img src="asset/img/logo30px.png" /><h3>all</h3></div></a>
    </li>
    <li id="printInteract" class="navCenter">
        <a id="activePrint" class="navBg" href="#"><div class="relativeCenter"><img src="asset/img/print.gif" /><h3>print</h3></div></a>
    </li>
    <li id="videoInteract" class="navCenter">
        <a id="activeVideo" class="navBg" href="#"><div class="relativeCenter"><img src="asset/img/video.gif" /><h3>video</h3></div></a>
    </li>
    <li id="webInteract" class="navCenter">
        <a id="activeWeb" class="navBg" href="#"><div class="relativeCenter"><img src="asset/img/web.gif" /><h3>web</h3></div></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**BOX HTML**

```
<div class="box">
<h1 title="Light me up"></h1>
<div class="innerbox">
    <figure>
        <img src="" />
    </figure>
    <ul class="categorySelect">
        <li class="print"></li>
        <li class="video"></li>
        <li class="web"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

ps. Sorry for the newbie question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code and add transitions like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //attach a single click listener on li elements
    $('li.navCenter').on('click', function () {
        var all = $(".box").find('.video, .print, .web');
        var activeCls = "." + this.id.replace("Interact", "");
        if (activeCls == ".all") {
            all.closest('.box').show();
        } else {
            var active = $(".box").find(activeCls);
            active.closest('.box').show();
            all.not(active).closest('.box').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

When you have this working, you can substitute a jQuery transition of your choice for the `.show()` and `.hide()` calls.

I have assumed that you want to hide/show the `.box` container for each item, but without seeing the real page HTML for the content you're hiding and showing, I can't be sure that's what you want to do.  Whatever you hide/show you will want to be consistent in both the `hide()` and the `show()` which your original code is not.

When selecting a transition to use, you will need to use something that works well when removing/adding multiple items.  fadeIn() and fadeOut() will probably not work well that way because when the item finally fades out, the remaining items will jump around.  I'm not sure what will work best.  Perhaps animating the width to zero.

Comment: damn you you're so close it's kinna on the fritz onclick but damn you're close I'll update the code?  btw i've seen every edit ty for your determination

Comment: http://designobvio.us/ie/# i've updated the code i'm trying to make sense of it all to fix it myself! but i'm sure you'll edit it before I can.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood - as you did not include the HTML for the `.box` and `.video, .print, .web` pieces, it's a bit of a guess what the most efficient way to hide/show those is and we don't have a way to test possible solutions.  I edited again.  I'm assuming that you only want to hide/show the `.box` container which your original code was only doing sometimes.

Comment: arg i'm so sorry i'll toss it up in the OP asap

Comment: done done sorry about that would you comment out the script.. I really want to understand this but that activeCLs doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: `activeCls` will be `.all`, `.print`, `.video` or `.web`.  Rather than test for it, you just remove `"Interact"` from the id and use the resulting value directly as a class name.  Now that I've seen your actual page, you need to use something other than `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()` to get a smooth transition.  I'd suggest first making sure it all works with just `hide()` and `show()` and then worry about adding a transition that looks good.

Comment: right now it's only grabbing the unique of .print .video or .web... some boxes have one of each class... I fixed this in the first iteration; however, trying to fix it in your seems overwhelming.updated code http://www.designobvio.us/ie/

Comment: arg well I think i'mma have to just live with my old code because the last script was a major feat for me to write this ones impossible for me to understand fully, let alone edit :c